# mysql - how to select 3 values (negative value) with LIMIT?

Tags: mysql, pagination

My page looks like:

| << back button | IMAGE | forward button >> |

Every row have an unique ID number, and with that ID I'm getting result from my data base.

The << back button is a hyperlink, and it should contain the previous row ID. The forward button >> should contain the next row ID.

The `ID` column has INTEGER values with AUTO_INCREMENT.

How I should wrote my query? Can I use negative values? Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `db` ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT -1, 1
```

Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use negative values, but you can use your current `id` in the `WHERE` clause to find values less than it, order by `ID DESC` and limit to 3. The `auto_increment` id column is sorted in descending order, so the first 3 values that are less than your currently selected id will be targeted.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `db`
WHERE `ID` < [your_current_id]
ORDER BY `ID` DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Likewise to get the next three, use `>` and sort in ascending order.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `db`
WHERE `ID` > [your_current_id]
ORDER BY `ID` ASC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't do that.

if you're going purely by IDs for your pageination, then somethign like

```
next 10 records:
    select ... where id > $current_id order by id ASC limit 10
previous 10 records:
    select ... where id < $current_id order by id DESC limit 10
```

would do, but then you're stuck with only allowing to browse by IDs in order. A proper pagination function disassociates the field you're sorting by from the navigation thing. You store **PAGE* NUMBERS** into the previous/next link, then use the total number of records in the pagination set to figure out row offsets for use in the LIMIT, e.g.